# $f_n(x)=\int_0^1 \frac{x(t)}{t^n}dt$ is given For what value of $n$, $f_n(x)\in L_p^*[0,1]$, (p>1)?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

$f_n(x)=\displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{x(t)}{t^n}dt$ is given .
For what value of $n$, $f_n(x)\in L_p^*[0,1]$, ($p>1$)?

It is an exercise problem but I cannot understand the notation, Can you give me hint? I am self studying functional analysis.

Comment: Which notation is unclear for you?

Comment: Try to bound $|f_n(g)|\le c\|g\|_p$. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each $f_n$ is a linear map from $L_p[0,1]$ into $\mathbb{C}$ (or $\mathbb{R}$ if only real functions are considered).

By Holder's inequality (with $p>1$ and  $1/p+1/q=1$)
$$|f_n(x)|\leq\|x\|_p\Big(\int^1_0t^{-nq}\,dt\Big)^{1/q}$$
which is finite as long as the integral $\int^1_0\frac{1}{t^{nq}}\,dt<\infty$. This we know happens if $nq<1$, in which case $f_n$ is a bounded linear functional on $L_p[0,1]$ and its norm is given by
$$\|f_n\|=\Big(\int^1_0t^{-nq}\,dt\Big)^{1/q}$$

---

For there values of $p$, one can see that $f_n$ may not be defined on the whole space $L_p$, and may failed to be bounded in a subspace $A_n\subset L_p$ where $f_m$ is defined.

---

Answer (score 1):

We know that $(L^p[0,1])^* \cong L^q[0,1]$ where $\frac1p + \frac1q = 1$. Therefore using this isomorphism we get
$$f_n \in (L^p[0,1])^* \iff \frac1{t^n} \in L^q[0,1] \iff \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{t^{nq}} < +\infty \iff nq < 1 \iff n < 1-\frac1p.$$